# Using maxTimeMS parameter with aggregation queries on Mongo 2.6 and Pymongo 2.7.1

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

- I'm unable to use maxTimeMS parameter with Mongo 2.6 and Pymongo 2.7.1
- As per the documentation on this page [Official Mongodb Aggregation Page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) the aggregation method should return a `Cursor` object. However, when I run the query locally on a `mongod` instance (2.6+) with `pymongo` 2.7.1, I get a `dict` object!

> In [14]: obj = coll.aggregate({'$group': {'_id': '$l', 'n': {'$sum':
>   1}}})
>
> In [15]: type(obj) Out[15]: dict

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use maxTimeMS with pymongo aggregation.

```
c.foo.bar.aggregate([], maxTimeMS=1000)
{u'ok': 1.0, u'result': []}
```

If you want a cursor:

```
for result in c.foo.bar.aggregate([], cursor={}, maxTimeMS=1000):
... print result
```

The aggregate command didn't support cursors before MongoDB 2.6 so it had to be added as an option to avoid breaking existing applications.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the [driver documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) where it is described that in order to return a cursor, you need to specify the arguments in addition to the pipeline in your `.aggregate()` method:

```
cursor = coll.aggregate([{'$group': { '_id': '$l', 'n': {'$sum': 1} }}],cursor={})
```

Note that the returned object here is a [CommandCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/command_cursor.html#pymongo.command_cursor.CommandCursor) and not a [cursor](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor).

This is because various modifiers such as `.limit()` and `.skip()` and other options do not apply in the context of an aggregation result. As such [**`$maxTimeMS`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/#op._S_maxTimeMS) is not a valid option for this type of cursor.

In addition, it would not do what you think it will even where valid. The reason being that the "cursor" execution is only counted "after" the "aggregation pipeline" execution is complete, so in this case, just fetching the results.

Look at the [`.currentOp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) and [`.killOp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.killOp/) implementations for other ways to control long running aggregation tasks.

Comment: Actually I got the answer. You can pass 'maxTimeMS' as an argument to the aggregate method (just like cursor) and it will work.